# Is this usage of past perfect continuous correct?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

For years that negativity **had been softening** because of high oil prices and relatively high economic growth, but know it’s gone.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Does the choice of past perfect continuous optimal?

Answer (score 1):

If you're speaking of a process which lasted into the approximate present, which "now it **is** gone" implies, then you should use a present perfect. A past perfect must be anchored in a past time before which the eventuality it mentions occurs.

Answer (score 0):

"For years that negativity had been softening because of high oil prices and relatively high economic growth, and *now* it *was* gone."

OR

"For years that negativity has been softening because of high oil prices and relatively high economic growth, and *now* it's gone."

Make sure the tenses in each clause match.